# How to upgrade select one of my other xhtml page?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have a jsf form of registration that usually works on a select one menu is displayed a list of vehicles, in case the user needs to register a new vehicle for the issuance of the note he clicks one side of the select menu and opens a dialog to register .
Until then everything is working but when I close the dialog the registered vehicle only appears after typing F5. How can I do to update the select one menu. It is important to point out that the registration of the notes and open dialog xthmml are different pages, so do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `styleClass="vehicles"` to `<p:selectOneMenu>`, and `update="@(.vehicles)"` on `<p:commandButton>` in the dialog (the button in the dialog that adds the new vehicle). If everything is wired up correctly in the managed bean (the list that select one menu displays is updated), you should see the new car in the list.

```
<p:selectOneMenu styleClass="vehicles" ...>

<p:commandButton update="@(.vehicles)" ...>
```

Comment: @cassiafreitas I've edited my answer, hopefuly it is more clearer now.

Comment: It did not work. This method works with different components in xhtml pages?